# what changed in play framework 2.x

Tags: module, console, dependencies, playframework-2.0

doesn't play framework 2.0.4 support some consoles?

when i was using 1.x, i could use the console "play eclipsify"

and "play dependencies" to fbconnect and fbgraph modules

but from when i chaged the version, it's not working.

then how can i connect those modules? i've no idea to do that

i think the new version doesn't support those consoles for modules

is it correct?

is the way totally different? if then please let me know.

---

also juz awhile ago i checked the 1.2.5 version

and there is no dependencies.yml and module folder

would you let me know what changed and how can i apply and adjust?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/Play-2.0-for-Play-1.x-developers

check this out

and i wanna tell you some people who evaluate my question

what if there is no begginer who really want to learn and ask, how developing survives?

i hate reputations!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's TOTALY different, although some ideas are the same, [`Play 2.x`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/playframework-2.0) is quite new product (as stated in *many* topics and questions since *many* months), there's (fortunately) no backward compatibility between [`Play 1.x`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/playframework-1.x) and [`2.x`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/playframework-2.0)!

When you'll visit [Play 1.x (only) modules page](http://www.playframework.org/modules) the first thing you'll see will be that disclaimer:

> These modules are for the **Play 1.x** series only. **Play 2.0** modules can be hosted anywhere on any Ivy, Maven or Git repository. We will add a directory for them here shortly.

Thanx to **Pere Villega** you can also search for [`Play 2.0 for Java`](http://www.playmodules.net/module/list?nameFilter=&versionFilter=2&inputTagFilter=) or [`Scala`](http://www.playmodules.net/module/list?nameFilter=&versionFilter=3&inputTagFilter=) modules on [PlayModules.net](http://www.playmodules.net/) site, however you need carefully choose between [`Play 1.x`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/playframework-1.x) and [`Play 2.x`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/playframework-2.0) series.

For working with [eclipse](/questions/tagged/eclipse), check [the Play's 2.0 IDE documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/IDE).

Comment: thanks alot for you information biesior
the thing what i can't use is the console "eclipsify with-source=true" it's not working at play 2.x
can you? if then what did i wrong?
i already put the path to "C:\play;" and i even have used play 1.2.5
would you give me any tiny clue for me? thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not using Eclipse.

Comment: well... i need to withdraw my word ;;
suddenly it's working oops.. thank you so much for your concern!